# opening workbook by VBA doesn't update values

Tags: vba, excel

I have some cells in my workbook that are linked to some sheets, So. I'm using the following VBA command to open and close sheets to get the values updated automatically in those cells.

```
Workbooks.open ("FileName.csv")
Activeworkbook.close
Workbooks.open ("FileName2.csv")
Activeworkbook.close
Workbooks.open ("FileName3.csv")
Activeworkbook.close
```

However! There is only one cell (Let's call it "D5" for now) that doesn't update EVEN after I open and close it's linked sheet by the above VBA code. And the weird problem here. That it updates normally if I opened and closed the sheet manualy (by double clicking on the file).

NOTE: the used formula is exactly the same in those cells, Only the sheet reference is different.

Sample:

```
=VLOOKUP($D$2,'C:\[test.csv]test'!$A:$B,2,0)
```

Comment: What is the formula in that cell?  Is it different in any way to your other formulas?

Comment: It's the same exact formula. only the reference sheet is different .. (=VLOOKUP($D$2,'C:\Reports\Test.csv'!$A:$B,2,0)

Comment: Try calculating after opening the workbook with Application.Calculate

Comment: If the reference sheet is different in that formula to the reference sheets in the cells that are working, does that mean that `Test.csv` is not one of the workbooks you opened?  (i.e. the ones you called `Filename.csv`, `FileName2.csv` and `FileName3.csv` in your question).  Or does it mean that this is the only cell in your workbook that is referring to one of the workbooks you opened?

Comment: Sorry, I may have confused you a little bit. I have 3 cells `D1 & D2 & D3` that refers to 3 different sheets `FileName.csv`,`FileName2.csv`,`FileName3.csv`, When I use open and close VBA command.. `D1` & `D3` updates normally, However `D2` stays on `#NA` until I manually open `FileName2.csv` by double clicking.